# react native and formik to autofocus to next

Tags: react-native, formik

This is the code where I render Input values

```
           <View style={styles.dobContainer}>
                    <View>{this.renderInput('dd', 'DD', formikProps)}</View>
                    <View>{this.renderInput('mm', 'MM', formikProps)}</View>
                    <View>{this.renderInput('yyyy', 'YYYY', formikProps)}</View>
                  </View>
```

and this is renderInput function .I want to move focus to month if user has filled in two digits and samne from month to year .

```
renderInput = (field, placeholder, formikProps) => {
        console.log("formikProps", formikProps);
        const { values, errors, touched } = formikProps
        let refval;
        let ddref = React.createRef();
        let mmref =React.createRef();
        let  yyref =React.createRef();
        if( field ==='dd'){
          refval =ddref;
        }else if(field === 'yyyy'){
          refval = yyref;
        }
        else {
          refval = mmref;
        }
          
        console.log("refval is ",refval);
        return(
            <View>
                <TextInput
                maxLength = {2}
               
                ref={(refval) => { this.refval = refval}}
                 onChangeText={()=>this.valuesandMove(field,formikProps,refval)}
               
                keyboardType='numeric'
                style={styles.textDesign} 
                placeholder={placeholder}
                  />
                {formikProps.errors && formikProps.errors[field] && <Text style={styles.errorStyle}>{formikProps.errors && formikProps.errors[field]}</Text>}
            </View>
        )
      }
```

However using refs doesn't seem to be working .

```
  valuesandMove =(field,formikProps,refval) =>{
      
      formikProps.handleChange(field);
      console.log("movetonext",field,formikProps.values,refval);
      let dd = formikProps && formikProps.values && formikProps.values.dd;
      let mm = formikProps && formikProps.values && formikProps.values.mm;
      console.log("this.refs",this.refs);
      if(field == "dd"  && dd >9  && dd< 31 ){
       // this.refs.mm.focus();
      }
    }
```

I see this.refs to be empty .

Answer (score 1):

The only way I got it working

```
let mmref =React.createRef();
<InputFormik
                    formikKey="dd"
                    formikProps={formikProps}
                    placeholder="dd"
                    keyboardType="default"
                    autoCapitalize="words"
                    autoCorrect={false}
                    returnKeyType="next"
                    onSubmitEditing={() => {
                      mmref.focus();
                    }}
                  />

                  <InputFormik
                    formikKey="mm"
                    formikProps={formikProps}
                    ref={(child) => {
                      if (child) {
                        mmref = child.refProp;
                      }
                    }}
                    placeholder="mm"
                    keyboardType="default"
                    autoCapitalize="words"
                    autoCorrect={false}
                    returnKeyType="next"
                  />
```